# Excluding admin.php from working rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a working rewrite rule in my .htaccess file, it's supposed to redirect from pages ending with /, to without them.

So for example 
**http://mysite.com/gallery/** will redirect to 
**http://mysite.com/gallery**

The rewrite rule looks as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

and works 99%. The only problem I'm having is that I need to exclude this for

**http://mysite.com/admin.php/whatever_may_follow**

I'm not a pro on these rules, and was hoping if someone could give a pointer as to how I can exclude admin.php from the rule.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin.php$
```